# Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b

Tags: android, android-studio

find on my event log in android studio screen this-

8:50 AM Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b

8:50 AM Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b

8:50 AM Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b

HAXm device is not found but my vt-x is already enable what should i do? my laptop model dell inspiron n5050

Comment: do you have debug mode enabled on your device?

Comment: yes debug mode is enable. emulator is not working. even when i connect with phone it is not working. pls help